# Contents of Downloadable Data from ESRI website?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, data

I'm looking for the simple grey basemap to use in a map I'm working on, but want to download it.  It's one of the options with their dynamic data.  ESRI has no real order on their download page.  Anyone with a list of contents inside these data downloads? I figure the newer ones just have more updated data.

[image]

Comment: A "white" basemap? "Light Gray" is more common. At what scale?  Data & Maps is rather comprehensive, but you only really need one.  What with the way borders keep changing, you should probably use the most recent one.

Comment: They pack in all the free data they can.  I don't see an index anywhere (and I don't get my media through that interface). I only see ~10Gb with a #1 and #2 pair, (and what you want is likely to be in the smaller set).

Comment: It just looks very unorganized with the naming conventions.

Comment: The 2013 data bundle looks well organized to me.

Comment: Inside of them is very organized.  The naming conventions on the download site is what I was referring.  "Esri data & maps" "data and maps" with no sort order on the year.

Comment: Can't you click on the column headings to sort within the list of available products?  The media is named by what it had been called when the media was manufactured.  Renaming older products is a slippery slope.

Comment: You can, but they are named differently.  Some start with ESRI, some ArcMap and some Data.  It's not a huge deal, just surprising.

Comment: I'll pass a note, but doubt the D&M team has much sway on the product list.